# Facing issues in Search and filter functionality

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to create search and filter functionalities. They are working correctly only in the beginning. For example, when I type something in the input field in the search component, I am getting the expected result. But when I erase it or type some other categories again, it is showing empty results. The same issue is happening with filter too.

Here is Search component.

```
const Search:React.FC<Props> = ({problems,setProblems}) => {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const updateSearch=(e)=>{
    searchRes(e.target.value)
    setQuery(e.target.value)
      }
      const searchRes = (searching)=>{
        const search = problems.filter((item)=>{
          return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searching.toLowerCase())
        })
        setProblems(search)
      }
  return (
    <div>
    <input type="text" onChange={updateSearch} value={query} />
</div>
  )
}
```

I am fetching the problems data using this custom hook

```
    const [problems, setProblems] = useState<DBProblem[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getProblems = async () => {
            const q = query(collection(firestore, "problems"), orderBy("order", "asc"));
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
            const tmp: DBProblem[] = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                tmp.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() } as DBProblem);
            });
            setProblems(tmp);

        };

        getProblems();
    
    }, []);
    return problems;
}
```

I am fetching data in index.tsx and calling the search component like this

```
  const prbs = useGetProblems()
  const [problems,setProblems] = useState<DBProblem[]>([])
  useEffect(() => {
      if (prbs) {
        setProblems(prbs);
      }
    }, [prbs]);


<div className='w-full flex'>
      <Search problems={problems} setProblems={setProblems}/>
      <Filter problems={problems} setProblems={setProblems} category='Array'/>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are, in quite a few places, copying data in several places. This is almost always an antipattern.

Code that takes a piece of data available to a component, and when it changes, puts that same data or a derivative of it into a new state item local to the component, is by definition pointless. Not only that, but you now have to manage two different pieces of state and ensure that they are synced, which opens up a whole category of bugs for no gain. For example:

```
const [problems,setProblems] = useState<DBProblem[]>([])
  useEffect(() => {
      if (prbs) {
        setProblems(prbs);
      }
    }, [prbs]);
```

This code copies `prbs` into `problems`. There is no point in doing this since `prbs` can be referenced directly.

In your case, what is happening is that when you search, the *copy* of problems in `index.tsx` is updated with a subset of the data from the custom hook (`useGetProblems`). When you then do a further search, it further filters the results of the *previous search* rather than the original unfiltered data. This is exactly the kind of bug caused by copying state around.

You do not want to store the filtered results in the state *at all* since it can be computed from other state. Instead, you want to take the original data from `useGetProblems`, as well as the search string, and compute on-the-fly the resulting filtered data. Note that computing this does *not* mean you need to *store* the results data itself in state. Doing so would be storing a derivate value, which leads to code that is hard to manage and bug-prone.

To do this without copying the state around, you [lift the state up](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components) to a parent where it can be accessed directly. The search string does not belong to `<Search>`, but instead its parent, because it is needed by the parent to compute the results.

```
const Search: React.FC<Props> = ({ onChange, value }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)} value={value} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

index.tsx

```
 const prbs = useGetProblems()
 const [searchString,setSearchString] = useState<DBProblem[]>([])

   const filteredProblems = prbs.filter((item)=>{
       return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchString.toLowerCase())
   })

  // filteredProblems can now be used in the JSX etc to reference the filtered data.



<div className='w-full flex'>
      <Search value={searchString} onChange={setSearchString}/>
 </div>
```

The same thing will need to happen with the `<Filters>`. The state of the filters will need to be managed in the parent. The `<Filter>` component will therefore read that state from props (without copying it into the local state), and also write that state using a callback; in the same way `<Search>` writes to `searchString` via its new `onChange` prop. The filter logic will then be applied in `index.tsx`, by updating the filter logic there.